# Python pattern match a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to pattern match a string, so that if it ends in the characters 'std' I split the last 6 characters and append a different prefix.

I am assuming I can do this with regular expressions and re.split, but I am unsure of the correct notation to append a new prefix and take last 6 chars based on the presence of the last 3 chars.

```
regex = r"([a-zA-Z])"
if re.search(regex, "std"):
    match = re.search(regex, "std")

#re.sub(r'\Z', '', varname)
```

Comment: I think regex is a bit of overkill for this. Try [`endswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a regex. Just use standard string methods:

```
if s.endswith('std'):
    s = s[:-6] + new_suffix
```

But if you had to use a regex, you would substitute a regex, you would substitute the new suffix in:

```
regex = re.compile(".{3}std$")

s = regex.sub(new_suffix, s)
```

Comment: The OP said "new prefix", not "new suffix".

Comment: @Błotosmętek He also said "append" instead of "prepend", so I wasn't quite sure.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, but yeah it just needs changed to '-6:'

Answer (score 4):

You're confused about how to use regular expressions here. Your code is saying "search the string 'std' for any alphanumeric character".

But there is no need to use regexes here anyway. Just use string slicing, and `.endswith`:

```
if my_string.endswith('std'):
    new_string = new_prefix + mystring[-6:]
```